# How find the $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: summation

Find the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

we know 
$$(2n-1)<2n$$
so
$$\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2^n}<\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$
so this sum is converge
I think use $\arcsin{x}$,But I can't,Thank you

Comment: Does x!! denote the factorial of x!?

Comment: Doesn't converge, according to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum((2n-1)!!%2F(2n!!)%2F2%5En)+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: @Sabyasachi: $x!!$ is the double factorial, and according to WA is converges to $\sqrt{2}$. You entered the wrong formula, try `sum((2n-1)!!/((2n)!!)/2^n)`

Comment: @gammatester my bad.

Comment: If $$\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2^n}<\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$ holds, then the summations must be less than 1, which it clearly isn't according to wolfram. I think the error is in the fact that $(-1)!$ isn't defined.

Comment: @Sabyasachi $(-1)!!=1$ by convention.

Comment: @MaMing yeah it's okay. Actually I made a calculation error, thinking, $$\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$$ while infact it is 2.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: by Binomial theorem or Taylor expansion:

$\sum \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}, \quad |x|<1$.

Comment: Ah the infamous binomial theorem.